# C# Regex.Split (How to build)

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'm trying to split lines like those:

```
root.MediaClip.MaxGroups=10
root.MediaClip.M0.Name=Burglar_Alarm_Short
root.MediaClip.M0.Location=/etc/audioclips/Burglar_Alarm_Short_8bit_32kHz_mono_PCM-16bit-little.wav
```

But I can't figure out how to stop splitting after a "=".

Here the result the split should have:

```
root
MediaClip
MaxGroups=10

root
MediaClip
M0
Name=Burglar_Alarm_Short

root
MediaClip
M0
Location=/etc/audioclips/Burglar_Alarm_Short_8bit_32kHz_mono_PCM-16bit-little.wav
```

The problem are lines which end with a file extension. But after the "=" has arrived there is no need for an additional split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex based split to only split on dots that are followed with any chars other than `=` and then `=` or end of string, and not preceded with `=`:

```
(?<=^[^=]*)\.(?=[^=]*(?:=|$))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%5B%5E%3D%5D*)%5C.(%3F%3D%5B%5E%3D%5D*(%3F%3A%3D%7C%24))&i=root.MediaClip.M0.Location).

The `(?<=^[^=]*)` is a positive lookbehind requiring the dot to appear after a start of string (`^`) that is followed with 0+ chars other than `=`, and `(?=[^=]*(?:=|$)` positive lookahead also requires a `=` or end of string (see `(?:=|$)` non-capturing group) after 0+ chars other than `=`.

In C#:

```
var chunks = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<=^[^=]*)\.(?=[^=]*(?:=|$))");
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! But now I see I forgot to mention the case when there is no "=" at all.

Comment: No problem, just add an end of string alternative to the lookahead: `(?<=^[^=]*)\.(?=[^=]*(?:=|$))`, I updated the answer to reflect this requirement.

Comment: Thanks! :) Not so easy if you use regex only 1 or 2 times a year. I really need to look deeper into some tutorials.